# How to stop PHP from rounding my barcode numbers

Tags: php, arrays, barcode, rounding

I have some bar code numbers in an array. PHP seems to be rounding the barcodes which start with leading zeros. How do I stop this happening and keep the numbers as they were? Code I am using is below:

```
$array = array(5032227448124,5060028999989,5010121096504,5060028999996,5016254104864,5016402052788,8422248036986,0000003798720,0000003735503,0000003798713);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

This echos the following, as you can see the last four bar codes which feature leading zeros have been changed and had their leading zeros removed. These numbers are always 13 digits long and are padded with zeros.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5032227448124
    [1] => 5060028999989
    [2] => 5010121096504
    [3] => 5060028999996
    [4] => 5016254104864
    [5] => 5016402052788
    [6] => 8422248036986
    [7] => 31
    [8] => 1030979
    [9] => 31
    [10] => 1031004
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote them as strings if they arent a number (integer, float, exponent).

Answer (score 0):

1. The obvious, easy, and also likely *wrong* answer is to make them strings.
2. The better answer is to use [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)/[`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to pad with zeroes:

   ```
    printf('%013d', 12345); // output: 0000000012345
   ```
3. MySQL also has a handy [`LPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function:

   ```
    SELECT LPAD(12345, 13, 0) // output 0000000012345
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to convert your values to padded strings:

```
$array = array_map(function ($e){return str_pad($e, 13, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just needed to put double quotes around each barcode number e.g.

```
 $array = array("5032227448124","5060028999989","5010121096504","5060028999996","5016254104864","5016402052788","8422248036986","0000003798720","0000003735503","0000003798713");
```

Comment: Just to clarify - it doesnt need to be double quotes, single will work just as well. Also this should be a comment on my answer since you selected that as the accepted answer and since its essentially what you did :-)